# Is there a way to make a Array unchangeable in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

`final` only can make a reference unchangeable.If I declare a array like this:

```
private final int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

I can change the value of `a[i]` just by using

```
a[i]++;
```

How can I do to make sure the element of array will not be changed during the program running?

Comment: You cannot make an array of `int`s immutable, what you *can* do is pass a copy of your array instead of the original one.

Comment: Not possible duplicate, definite duplicate.